# Any way for /tags to provide unanswered count?

Tags: feature-request, tags, unanswered

I am trying to get a count of unanswered questions by tag.  Basically if there was an 'unanswered-count' in addition to the 'count' property of the /tags response that would be perfect.

It has been suggested that I use /questions/unanswered with the tag filter.  However I would have to query the API thousands of times every time I wanted to update the unanswered count.  I just want the list of tags like it is on the right side of SO when you click on 'Unanswered'.

What I want to do is every five or 10 minutes get the top 10 tags by unanswered questions count, but to get the top 10 I have to know the count of all the others (so I know which ones are the top 10). Perhaps there is an algorithm that does not require one to go through the entire list of items to determine the top 10?

Answer (score 2):

You can get that by using the questions/unanswered route with the `tagged` parameter.

Comment: True, however with SO there are over 4,000 tags.  I would burn through the daily limit sometime during the third time I tried to get the unanswered count for all the tags.  Really I just want the top 10 or so, but I need to know the vast majority in order to determine the top 10 or so.